# Finding the position in a list with a while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have to use a while loop to find the position of a number in a list. If the number is not in the list, it should print "not in list". This is what I have so far, but after entering a number, nothing prints whether it is in the list or not.

```
myList = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]
i = 0
x = input("Enter a number")
while i < len(myList):
    if i == x:
        print("In position: ",i)
    else:
        i == i+1
```

Comment: Why do you have to use a loop for this? It's not the right way to accomplish this task.

Comment: And then it will still be infinite once it finds the index :)

Comment: I know how to do this using a for loop, but for my class we are supposed to use a while loop to help learn about them. Don't ask why!

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple problems in your code. First, you are confusing `i`, your counter which I assume you're trying to use to index `myList`, with the elements themselves. You aren't indexing `myList` anywhere. Second, you never convert the input into a number, and everything in `myList` is a number. Third, you are comparing `i` to `i+1` with `==` instead of reassigning with `=`.

```
myList = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]
i = 0
x = int(input("Enter a number"))
while i < len(myList):
    if myList[i] == x:
        print("In position: ", i)
    else:
        i = i+1 # i += 1
```

The most glaring issue, however, is that this is the wrong way to find an object in a `list`. Use the `index` method:

```
myList = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]
x = int(input("Enter a number"))
try:
    print("In position: ", myList.index(x))
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: And if the OP wants to find only the first instance, he can break from the loop once it's found. You also want some `found` flag so after going iterating over the list you want to check whether to print the not found message.